# why am I getting image instead of video from webcam using the underwritten code

Tags: python, pycharm, opencv

***The code i wrote was-***

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

***What should I change to get video output instead of image output.Please help.(Currently using pycharm).Whenever i run the code it gives some continuous picture outputs.***

Comment: Ok thanks guys. Now it's working after changing waitkey to 1. But does anyone know why am I getting an mirror like inverted video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the OpenCV docs, the general form of your video capture loop should look like this:

```
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()

while True:

    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # if frame is read correctly ret is True
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Your code isn't working as expected because you're calling `cv.waitKey(0)`. This will display the window infinitely until any keypress. You should call `cv.waitKey(1)` instead, as it will display the frame for 1 ms and move on to the next. The equality check with `ord('q')` allows the loop to `break` when you press the `Q` key only.

Answer (score 0):

```
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Your argument to `waitKey` should be `(1)`, not `(0)`.